# How can I get customer data based on the number of users they have?

Tags: mysql, count, subquery, having

I want to get customer data from all the businesses with more than 1 user.

For this I think I need a subquery to count more than 1 user and then the outer query to give me their emails.

I have tried subqueries in the WHERE and HAVING clause

```
SELECT   u.mail
FROM     users u
WHERE    count IN (
    SELECT count (u.id_business)
    FROM businesses b
    INNER JOIN users u ON b.id = u.id_business
    GROUP BY b.id, u.id_business
    HAVING COUNT (u.id_business) >= 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you do not need a subquery, everything can be achieved in a joined aggregate query with a `HAVING` clause, like :

```
SELECT u.mail 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN businesses b on b.id = u.id_business
GROUP BY u.id, u.email
HAVING COUNT (*) >= 2
```

NB : in case several users may have the same email, I have added the primary key of `users` to the `GROUP BY` clause (I assumed that the pk is called `id`) : you  may remove this if `email` is a unique field in `users`.

Comment: Thank you. This unfortunately gives me 0 results :(

Comment: @KatEl : that's weird... for me to debug, it would be good if you could provide sample data and expected output.